# Checking which target is executing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, target

So I have 2 targets: 1 is my application the other is for unit tests.

In my code I need to know which target its running in order to skip a block if code while running unit tests. Is this possible?

```
#ifdef "Some how figure out what target we are in"
// run this code if we are not running the unit test target
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In your unit test target build settings, you can add a Preprocessor Macro (called, for example TARGET_IS_UNIT_TESTING). Then as you say

```
#ifndef TARGET_IS_UNIT_TESTING
// run this code if we are not running the unit test target
#endif

#ifdef TARGET_IS_UNIT_TESTING
// run this code if we are running the unit test target
#endif
```

Comment: I need more information please, the link provided explains how to get it done in GCC settings and my build setting doesn't have any section for GCC